# Can overreporting the oil production cause a fall of the oil prices

Tags: supply-and-demand

The [top news today](https://www.google.ee/search?q=800K+Barrels+of+Oil+Disappeared) is a discovery that oil production was overreported by 800 thouthand barrel a day. Could it cause 5x price fall during the year? Such allegations challenge the market theory, IMO, which says that if your price depends on some agency report rather than supply and demand then market theory costs nothing, right?

Comment: Please could you at least link to the story of over-reporting that you're talking about? And please be a little more clear about what you mean by "market theory costs nothing"

Comment: Why would it challenge market theory? Information which drives expectations can very much influence events today in any standard model.

Comment: @BBKing Because the market is supply and demand. It is very strange to hear that some institution may define prices, breaking the connections with reality.